# What do the assembly instructions 'seta' and 'setb' do after repz cmpsb?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm having trouble understanding what the following lines of assembly do:

```
0x401810:    repz cmps BYTE PTR ds:[rsi],BYTE PTR es:[rdi]
0x401812:    seta   dl
0x401815:    setb   al
```

I understand after debugging, the first instruction compares the bytes in registers `rsi` and `rdi`, byte by byte.

Then it sets the lower bytes of `rdx` and `rax` according based on that instruction.

My confusion is, when I looked up this instruction online, it said `seta` sets the lower byte to 0x01 if its above a certain value, otherwise its 0x00. Similar for `setb`, which sets the byte to 0x01 if its below a certain value.

My question is what value, and how is it related to the above instruction?

Comment: `setCC` consults the flag bits, it doesn't care how they got set. `cmps` sets flag bits. So that's the connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`cmps` instruction](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/CMPS_CMPSB_CMPSW_CMPSD_CMPSQ) compares `[rsi]` and `[rdi]`. The [`repz` prefix](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/REP_REPE_REPZ_REPNE_REPNZ) (alternately spelled `repe`) means to increment `rsi` and `rdi` then repeat `cmps` as long as `[rsi]` and `[rdi]` compare equal. The `rflags` register will be set on each iteration; the final iteration where `[rsi]` ≠ `[rdi]` is what will be used by `seta` (set if above) and `setb` (set if below).

In other words, the C pseudocode for those 3 instructions would look like this:

```
// Initial values
uint8_t *rsi = (...);
uint8_t *rdi = (...);
uint64_t rcx = (...);

// repz cmps BYTE PTR [rsi], BYTE PTR [rdi]
while (*rsi == *rdi && rcx > 0) {
    rsi++;
    rdi++;
    rcx--;
}

uint8_t dl = *rsi > *rdi;   // seta dl
uint8_t al = *rsi < *rdi;   // setb al
```

See the documentation for all of the `setCC` instructions [here](https://github.com/HJLebbink/asm-dude/wiki/SETcc).

Comment: So where does the `seta` and `setb` come in?

Comment: @Varun lyer in the last two lines.

Comment: So you're comparing the pointers when setting `dl` and `al`? Not the values of the registers itself?

Comment: `*` is the dereference operator, @varun. He's comparing the values of the registers.

Comment: @VarunIyer values in the registers are the pointers (in asm), the compared values are values in memory (pointed at by the pointers/registers). (just to clear up the wording, it looks like you understand it correctly, i.e. `C *rsi == asm [rsi]`). And `setCC` does use the `rflag` as source of condition check, so that C code is explaining the functionality, not showing inner working details of ASM variant, instead doing the compares twice again.

Comment: @Ped7g yeah I know what a dereference is. I didn't notice that he initialized the `rsi` and `rdi` as pointers. I assumed they were initialized as integers, which is why I thought i.e. `*rsi` was a pointer, and not a dereference to the pointer.

Answer (score 5):

The instruction mnemonics are:

- `repz cmps ds:[esi], es:[edi]`
  Compare strings while the strings compare equal
- `seta dl`
  Set `dl` to 1 if the above flag is set, or dl to 0 if not
- `setb al`
  Set `al` to 1 if the below flag is set, or al to 0 if not

In addition to checking the zero flag, `repz` uses the `ecx` register to specify the maximum number of repetitions. (`ecx` is also called the counter register.)

[EDIT] as correctly pointed out by Jester below, there are no above and below flags, above and below are the result of bit operations on cpu status flags:

- above: CF = 0 and ZF = 0
- below: CF = 1

Comment: So the above flag and below flag are part of the eflags register?

Comment: The flags are set/reset by the cmps operation.

Comment: Reading these operations I'd say this looks like a strncmp() or similar operation.

Comment: There is no above and below flag, but there is carry and zero which are used to detect above/below. This is all well documented in the instruction set reference, e.g. "above (CF=0 and ZF=0)."